# Implemenation of SIP on android platform 2.1

Tags: android, sip

I want to work on SIP and Android. I am supposed to make it possible for two users to call eachother using iptel.org. One way to do this, I can use the demo provided with 2.3 but it needs a real device. As I don't have a real device, I wan't to work at 2.1 platform. I am a beginner, so I need a good step to start so that it would be easy for me to complete it.

Comment: I also working on same application can u please guide me or help me .I am fresher and need to do this project for my client. So please help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PJSIP ( http://www.pjsip.org/) is a good and portable SIP framework. It doesn't still have support for android (even if it is just a matter of time) but you could check out this : http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/ that is android SIP support built on PJSIP.

Comment: What do u think about jAIN sip sTACK? COULD WE USE IT FOR AUDIO STREAM EXCHANGE?

Comment: @Zahir: Yes, you can probably use Jain SIP.

Answer (score 2):

Android 2.1 doesn't have built-in support for SIP so you have to find a third party library.

Comment: i talked to my suppervisor regarding to use SIP API and he could give me two sets but they could support on 2.1 version. Is that possible to upgrade these two sets to 2.3 platform so that i can use built in sip support???

Comment: if it is possible, could you describe it regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2):

JAIN-SIP http://jsip.java.net/ is also a very good SIP-Stack including a reference implementation of the SIP API.
It works on great on Android <= 2.2.

Here's (http://groups.google.com/group/mobicents-public/browse_thread/thread/e38fbdd874083d49/4fdb4123419e7a74) a nice discussion with further information.